# Create new or select object in a ForeignKey in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models, model A and model B.

In model B I have two ForeignKey fields which refers to the model A. It works, but it requires the model A to have records before I can choose values in model B. What is the best way to create a form in which I can choose to create a new record in Model A and selecting it or choosing a pre-existing record?

Answer (score 1):

Look into django (model)formsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).

These are made for this reason. with either inline or model formsets you can easily create page where you can edit both model A and B and even save them together.

If you look into formsets questions @ stackoverflow and django docs - i am sure you will figure it out.

Alan